# Converting Magnetism to electricity

Tags: generator, electricity, magnet

I've been seeing a lot of videos online of people using neodymium magnets to make a motor spin to generate electricity.

If we can generate electricity from magnets why isnt this being used more often?

I'm assuming there are limitations.
E.g heat or the amount of energy the magnets can generate?

Can someone explain why this isnt a viable source for power?

**Edit:**
apparently all the videos are fakes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've been seeing a lot of videos online of people using neodymium
>   magnets to make a motor spin to generate electricity.

Please link one or at least further explain what they do in the video, a lot of people do bogus videos where "free energy" is generated by magnets

> If we can generate electricity from magnets why isnt this being used
>   more often?

Any electric generator uses magnets or electromagnets to convert mechanical energy to electrical energy.

> I'm assuming there are limitations. E.g heat or the amount of energy
>   the magnets can generate?

The energy is not generated by the magnet, but by the movement of the magnet and its magnetic field. You can always use a larger/stronger magnet but then you would need to put way more effort/force to move the magnet

> Can someone explain why this isnt a viable source for power?

Magnets are used on any electric generator, though they will not create energy by themselves.

Comment: Oops turns out the videos are bs I'll post a link to one

Comment: ABB make [7 megawatt permanent magnet generators for wind farms](https://new.abb.com/motors-generators/generators/generators-for-wind-turbines/permanent-magnet-generators/high-speed-permanent-magnet-generators)